# SQL - Select all primary keys for set of columns with duplicate values

Tags: mysql

consider table as-

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM DB;

+------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| UDID | BENEID | DEPT | SCHEME     | NAME    |
+------+--------+------+------------+---------+
|    1 |     55 | TCS  | RC         | SHELLY  |
|    2 |     95 | TCS  | RC         | BOB     |
|    3 |     75 | TCS  | RC         | ULRICH  |
|    4 |     55 | TCS  | RC         | SHELLY  |
|    5 |     85 | TCS  | FS         | SHELLY  |
|    6 |     65 | DSSP | ABC        | BOB     |
|    7 |     65 | DSSP | ABC        | BOB     |
|    8 |     75 | DSSP | ABC        | ULRICH  |
+------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

there are duplicate values for the set of columns **beneid, dept** and **scheme**, with different **primary key, udid**. that is,

```
mysql> SELECT DEPT, SCHEME, BENEID, COUNT(*) AS CN FROM DB GROUP BY 1, 2, 3 HAVING CN >1;
+------+--------+--------+----+
| DEPT | SCHEME | BENEID | CN |
+------+--------+--------+----+
| DSSP | ABC    |     65 |  2 |
| TCS  | RC     |     55 |  2 |
+------+--------+--------+----+
```

we have 2 duplicate columns for dept, scheme, beneid but with different primary keys (udid).
how can i list out the udids for the above result ?

expected table structure -

```
+------+--------+--------+----+-----+
| DEPT | SCHEME | BENEID | CN | UDID|
+------+--------+--------+----+-----+
| DSSP | ABC    |     65 |  2 | 6   |
| DSSP | ABC    |     65 |  2 | 7   |
| TCS  | RC     |     55 |  2 | 1   |
| TCS  | RC     |     55 |  2 | 4   |
+------+--------+--------+----+-----+
```

Comment: Please stop shouting

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for reply. It is MySQL. I wanted to avoid DISTINCT keyword.

Comment: Why avoid DISTINCT? Aesthetic reasons?

Comment: @Strawberry Because the table has over 100 Mi row with disk size of 120 GB. Distinct will scan tables so many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "go back" to the original table, by filtering this table for rows which you have found as being duplicates.

Example:

```
SELECT DB.DEPT, DB.SCHEME, DB.BENEID, DUPS.CN, DB.UID
FROM DB
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT DEPT, SCHEME, BENEID, COUNT(*) AS CN
    FROM DB GROUP BY 1, 2, 3 HAVING CN >1
  ) AS DUPS ON DB.DEPT = DUPS.DEPT
     and DB.SCHEME = DUPS.SCHEME
     and DB.BENEID = DUPS.BENEID
```

Comment: *You need* as in *how you need to change the way the look at the data* and not as *this is the only way to do it*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aggregate query you listed as a subquery and wrap it with an `exists` call:

```
SELECT *
FROM   db a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT   b.dept, b.scheme, b.beneid
               FROM     db b
               WHERE    a.dept = b.dept AND 
                        a.scheme = b.scheme AND
                        a.beneid = b.beneid
               GROUP BY b.dept, b.scheme, b.beneid
               HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1)
```